# Android push notification without GCM works in background service but push notification is showing up before estimated time

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I create an android application which can show a push notification each five minutes . I have add something special to this application . This can show a push notification when app is closed . It means this is working on background service .

Also , This can show a notification with the restart of the device. All these processes should work after each five minutes . But , this notification shows before the estimated time .

**NOTE**

I didn't use GCM for my application.

Here are the steps which I use ,

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private int MID = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Alaram Fired")
                .setContentText("Events To be PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify(MID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
        MID++;

    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        intent = new Intent(MyService.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MyService.this.getSystemService(MyService.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 5, pendingIntent);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.context=this;
    }

    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }

    // Method to stop the service
    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.agent_app.mynotification">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service android:name=".MyService"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.agent_app.mynotification.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

What should I do to make this work after each five minutes ?

Have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the OS arranges alarm calls from various applications in such a way that there will be minimum wakeup calls to the device so as to minimize the battery drain. It is recommended that the alarm frequency should be as low as possible to prevent battery drain (not less than 30 minutes).

From the docs,

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set) link for complete details.

Comment: So , Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Refer the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html. It suggests to use `setWindow()` or `setExact()`. But advises that *only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time delivery (such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time) should be scheduled as exact. Applications are strongly discouraged from using exact alarms unnecessarily as they reduce the OS's ability to minimize battery use*